# Firebase changes not being automatically reflected on page

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I am successfully updating an inner node on my Firebase Realtime Database by doing the following:

```
...
constructor() {
  private db: AngularFireDatabase
}
...    
function updateName(node, innerNode, newName) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.db.database
      .ref('nodes/' + node.key + '/innerNodes/' + innerNode.key + '/name')
      .set(newName)
      .then(() => resolve())
      .catch((e) => reject(e));
  })
}
```

But my page data is not being automatically updated after that. It requires a page reload for me to see the changes.

On regular updates (where I simply do `db.list(PATH).update(uid, {key:value})`) changes are immediately reflected on my pages. Indeed I do have a working example on the very same application.

I read about this being a NgZone issue, but I couldn't make it work.

Could anyone help me figure out what is wrong with my code?

UPDATE:

Here's where I should see the result:

```
<h1 [(ngModel)]="innerNode.name"></h1>
<button (click)="updateName(node, innerNode, 'New name')" type="button">Change to new name</button>
```

Comment: Show some code where data should change...frontend

Comment: I have just posted an update.

Comment: try use innerNode.name|Async or {{ (innerNode)?.name}} if innerNode is a object

Comment: Yes it is an object.. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: <h1>{{innerNode.name}}</h1> try this. Im assuming that you object are receive this updated data of RTDB.

Comment: Still not working. I think it's about the way I am updating (using db.database.ref().set() instead of db.list().update(). Actually I tried changing from .set() to .update() but yet no success.